# SQL Query with multiple columns w/ different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I create a query that is querying 1 table and wanting to return multiple clauses but has different conditions for each column.  I also need a group by clause at the end too. Something like below where my bracket is psuedocode:

```
Select date, sum(revenue) [where source = X], sum (revenue [where source = Y]
from table1 
group by date
```

Is this possible or do I just need to do different queries

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select date,
       sum(case when source = 'X' then revenue end) as x_revenue,
       sum(case when source = 'Y' then revenue end) as y_revenue
from t
group by date;
```